# sbpl installation problem

Tags: ros, installation, sbpl-lattice-planner, sbpl, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I'm trying to install the sbpl package on Ubuntu 12.04.
I installed `ros-groovy-sbpl` with apt-get but when I run :

```
$ rosmake sbpl_lattice_planner
```

I get the following output :

```
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                            
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['sbpl_lattice_planner']                               
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/<me>/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130208-110917
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['sbpl_lattice_planner'] to:
[]                                  
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages:   ['sbpl_lattice_planner']
[ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.
```

I tried `rosdep update` and resourcing `setup.bash` already.

Thanks for any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54720/sbpl-installation-problem/) by [victorp](https://answers.ros.org/users/4163/victorp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2013-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

sbpl_lattice_planner is part of the navigation_experimental stack:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/sbpl_lattice_planner
You need to download that one into a rosbuild workspace to rosmake it.

ros-groovy-sbpl only contains the core c/c++ code.

If you followed instructions that seem to be missing information, please point us to the URL (mask it a bit so that you can post it).

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1